# Mkdocs Warning: 404 GET require.js

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

I've worked using Mkdocs before but when I upgraded/re-installed Python, Pip, and Mkdocs, any contents made though Markdown does not show; the build is successful and shows my webpage through localhost but outputs no content from Markdown. Rather, there's a warning that shows on my VSCode terminal that seems to need a 'require.js' file - am I missing a file?

```
    [I 180612 09:20:16 server:292] Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8000  
    [I 180612 09:20:16 handlers:59] Start watching changes  
    [I 180612 09:20:16 handlers:61] Start detecting changes  
    [W 180612 09:20:23 web:2064] 404 GET /mkdocs/js/require.js (127.0.0.1) 2.30ms  
    [W 180612 09:20:24 web:2064] 404 GET /mkdocs/js/require.js (127.0.0.1)
    0.00ms  
    [I 180612 09:21:07 handlers:132] Browser Connected: http://127.0.0.1:8000/3-product-setup/product-messages-about/
```

Also checked my mkdocs installation:

```
    PS C:\xampp\htdocs\surefiresystems-help\rms-user-docs> pip show mkdocs  
    Name: mkdocs  
    Version: 0.17.4  
    Summary: Project documentation with Markdown.  
    Home-page: http://www.mkdocs.org  
    Author: Tom Christie  
    Author-email: tom@tomchristie.com  
    License: BSD  
    Location: c:\users\surefire\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages  
    Requires: Markdown, click, tornado, livereload, PyYAML, Jinja2  
    Required-by:
```

Here are my Python and PIP versions:

```
 

    PS C:\xampp\htdocs\surefiresystems-help\rms-user-docs> python --version  
    Python 3.5.0  
    PS C:\xampp\htdocs\surefiresystems-help\rms-user-docs> pip --version  
    pip 10.0.1 from c:\users\surefire\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.5)
```

I also added the suggested path (upon successful installation of mkdocs) on my environment variables.

Thank you

Comment: `require.js` seems to be used for search. I have it located at `/Web/mkdocs/general/site/search/require.js` and `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mkdocs/contrib/legacy_search/templates/search/require.js`

Comment: I just did a fresh install of the latest version (0.17.4) and did not encounter this problem at all. Try re-running the install to make sure it completed properly??

Comment: Also possibly relevant: what theme are you using?

Comment: I notice that the requested path is `/mkdocs/js/require.js`. However, on 0.17, the file should be at `search/require.js`. My guess would be that you are using an older theme which is not compatible with the most recent version of MkDocs. Which theme are you using?